# mysql update columns based on digits

Tags: mysql

I have this kind of data.

```
ID
1899
11999
008999
```

I need to update the data into this.I just need to fill the '0' or '00' in front and remains if sufficient 6 digits.

```
ID
001899
011999
008999
```

Comment: What is the datatype of id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First change Data-type of that column to char

```
ALTER TABLE `table` CHANGE `id` `id` CHAR(6);
```

Then use LPAD()

```
UPDATE table SET `id`=LPAD(`id`, 6, '0');
```

Comment: `LPAD(TRIM(id), 6, '0');` after `CHAR(6)` (but indeed `VARCHAR` is not needed, and INT impossible).

Comment: ```TRIM()``` will not be required as data is already trimmed when it was stored as ```INT()```

Comment: `008999` suggests `VARCHAR` but that could indeed be a copy error.

Comment: @JoopEggen Can you post the error message so i can look into it.

Comment: congrats; I meant an error in typing the question, in the section "I have this kind of data".

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest *not* doing this update, and not storing your numeric data as text.  Instead, if you need to view the numbers with padded zeroes, just handle that when you query, e.g.

```
SELECT RIGHT(CONCAT('000000', ID), 6) AS ID_padded
FROM yourTable;
```

Strictly speaking we should also cast `ID` to text before calling `CONCAT`, but MySQL should be able to cope with this via implicit conversion.